# systemd is missing on mac osx 10.8.4

Tags: hadoop, homebrew, systemd

My original goal is to install hadoop, but I am stuck at the "ssh localhost" step.

ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Few online helps such as http://zhegu.wordpress.com/2012/10/30/connect-to-host-localhost-port-22-connection-refused/

give me hint to use systemctl to enable sshd, but then I found I don't have systemctl in /usr/bin

Another hint is to install systemd package to have systemctl. Yet I found no further info about where I can get systemd.

It appears doable to install hadoop on osx 10.7 though. (http://dennyglee.com/2012/05/08/installing-hadoop-on-osx-lion-10-7/) So I speculate there should be some way to overcome my problem.

Thanks ahead for any helps!

Comment: In "System Preferences / Sharing", is "Remote session" enabled? I don't have `systemctl` anywhere on my Mac either, but ssh is working like a charm. I'm running 10.8.4 too.

Comment: sbooob, you are amazingly correct! it works now. :)

Comment: look at `launchd`. This is on Mac, and is similar to systemd.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really install systemd on osx. It's a linux thing.